# textAngular toolbar changing height

Tags: html, css, textangular

I'm using [textAngular](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular) as a wysiwyg editor.

But i got problem with displaying the toolbar properly.

From the `pre` (quote) button on, the icon height jumps from 47*34px to 39*28 px and jumps back again to 47*34px at charcount() icon.

here is my html :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <h1 class="col-sm-12">Select the kind of evaluation you want to achieve</h1>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="template in templatesList">
            {{ template.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- <div ng-show="htmlVariable">{{ htmlVariable }}</div> 
-->

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div text-angular ng-model="htmlVariable" class="ta-editor"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's the result :
[image]

thx for ur help in advance

Comment: Could you post some of the icon HTML? The code you've posted doesn't show this.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean with icon html. This is an angular directive (`<div text-angular>`) that requires font-awesome which is correctly inserted in my index.html